# Manipulating ItemTemplate interntal controls in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the code below, I want to change `<%# Eval("name") %>` to `<%# Eval("role") %>` at run-time when the user is in a certain role. How can I do this in code behind (C#)?

In particular, I want to use `User.IsInRole("Admin")` to do this.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="comment">
        <asp:Label class="name" runat="server" ID="NAME"> <%# Eval("name") %> </asp:Label>
        <asp:Label class="date" runat="server" Text='<%# "Posted on: " + Eval("date") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label class="message" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Message") %>'></asp:Label>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Update: I am using ListView.

Comment: Would adding the user's role to the SQL query be an option?  That way you can return the correct data from the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you fetch the data from a enumerable of objects of type **Post** (from linq/collection/whatever...), in the aspx:

```
...
<asp:Label class="name" runat="server" ID="NAME">
      <%# ProcessName(Container.DataItem as Post) %>
</asp:Label>
...
```

in the code behind:

```
protected string ProcessName(Post post){
    if(User.IsInRole("Admin")){
        return post.Name;
    }
    return post.Role;
}
```

maybe you can evaluate the IsInRole before the binding so you don't have to execute on every row.

Comment: I am not sure. Will it work if I am using SqlDataSource with ListItem? VS2010 underlines with red when typing `Post` in `Container.DataItem as Post`.

Comment: I think this will work if there is an alternative for _Post_ in SqlDataSource.

Comment: With a SqlDataSource you can use a DataRow or DataRowView instead of Post

Answer (score 2):

Could you possibly use a ternary operator for this? (not certain of this myself)

```
<%# condition ? Eval("name") : Eval("role") %>
```

or in case of VB.NET

```
<%# If(condition, Eval("name"), Eval("role")) %>
```

Comment: I think I didn't make it clear enough. I want to check if User.IsInRole("Admin") which is only possible in code behind. Am I wrong?

Comment: I assume you want to view messages differently, if the currently logged-in user has the "Admin" role?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I want.

Comment: Well, it seems that `User.IsInRole()` is accessible from inside the control. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to Joachim, I got this simple solution:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="comment">
    <asp:Label class="name" runat="server" ID="NAME"> <%# User.IsInRole("Admin") ? Eval("role") : Eval("name") %> </asp:Label>
    <asp:Label class="date" runat="server" Text='<%# "Posted on: " + Eval("date") %>'></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label class="message" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Message") %>'></asp:Label>
</div>
```